# SQL constraints and ON DELETE

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given an simple example of foreign key constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  product_no integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name text,
  price numeric
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  shipping_address text,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE order_items (
  product_no integer REFERENCES products ON DELETE CASCADE,
  order_id integer REFERENCES orders ON DELETE CASCADE,
  quantity integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_no, order_id)
);
```

When a row is deleted from products or orders, referencing rows from order_items are also deleted.

But - it is possible to have the database detect orphaned rows from products or orders (rows for which there is no referencing order_item) and delete them? I know I could set up a query to do it easily enough, but in a larger more complex schema, that could be a lot of queries. I'm wondering if there's a similar mechanism to ON DELETE CASCADE?

Comment: You won't be able to add a row to order_items table that has no reference to parents tables. Why do you need to fine orphaned rows?

Comment: I know. The reason for finding orphaned rows is for a periodic purge of old data, and finding as easy way to remove rows which are no longer referenced anywhere. For example, in the above schema, just suppose I wanted have rows automatically deleted from products for which there is no order_item?

Comment: I mean if you have those reference columns you don't need to take care about it. DB will do stuff

Comment: Yes, cascade delete works quite well. (check deferrable, initially deferred, though). But in this particular case, I don't think (cascading) delete is a good choice. Do you *really* want to cancel every pending order if a product is deleted from the table? do you really *want* to delete a product from the table? What about history? Do you want processed orders to be deleted, just because someone chooses to "clean up" the products or customers tables? Should this cascade into accounting, too ;-?

Comment: My app does not really have orders and products, they are just examples of the sort of relationships. It is a requirement for me to 'clean up', including deleting rows from the 'one' side of one-to-many relationships where no matching rows from the 'many' side exist. It's the other way round from the constraint checking, which ensures that rows on the 'many' side are present in 'one'.

Comment: Ah, I see: you want the dependency inverted. You could hack some scheme with triggers and reference counts. (or even without reference counts) It is relatively easy if you can guarantee stable keys (no PK updates)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example without reference counts:

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE one
    ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , name VARCHAR
    );
CREATE TABLE two
    ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , name VARCHAR
    );
CREATE TABLE onetwo
    ( one_id INTEGER REFERENCES one(id)
    , two_id INTEGER REFERENCES two(id)
        , PRIMARY KEY(one_id, two_id)
    );
CREATE INDEX onetwo_rev ON onetwo (two_id,one_id);

  -- Populate the tables.
INSERT INTO one(name) select 'One_name_' || gs::text FROM generate_series(1,5) gs ;
INSERT INTO two(name) select 'Two_name_' || gs::text FROM generate_series(1,5) gs ;
INSERT INTO onetwo (one_id, two_id)
SELECT o.id, t.id
FROM one o
JOIN two t ON 1=1
        ;
  -- Remove some random associations between one&two,
  -- and remove any unreferenced records from one and two
DELETE FROM onetwo WHERE random() < 0.7;
DELETE FROM one dd WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM onetwo ot WHERE ot.one_id=dd.id) ;
DELETE FROM two dd WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM onetwo ot WHERE ot.two_id=dd.id) ;

SELECT * FROM onetwo;
SELECT * FROM one;
SELECT * FROM two;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_the_deletes() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $meat$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM one dd
    WHERE dd.id=OLD.one_id
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM onetwo ot WHERE ot.one_id=dd.id)
       ;
    DELETE FROM two dd
    WHERE dd.id=OLD.two_id
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM onetwo ot WHERE ot.two_id=dd.id)
       ;
    RETURN NEW;
END; $meat$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_last_sale
    AFTER DELETE ON onetwo
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_the_deletes()
     ;

SELECT o.name AS name1
        , t.name AS name2
FROM onetwo ot
JOIN one o ON o.id = ot.one_id
JOIN two t ON t.id = ot.two_id
        ;

  -- Delete some random associations
  -- the trigger should also remove any unreferenced rows
  -- from one and two tables.
DELETE FROM onetwo WHERE random() < 0.4;

SELECT o.name AS name1
        , t.name AS name2
FROM onetwo ot
JOIN one o ON o.id = ot.one_id
JOIN two t ON t.id = ot.two_id
        ;
SELECT * FROM one;
SELECT * FROM two;
```